# Java RMI call with remote parameters fails

Tags: java, rmi

I obtain a remote reference from an RMI registry; lets call it `s`. Now, `s` is of (interface) type `S` which offers a method `m(A, B, int)`.

On the client, I have implementations of `A` and `B` which both extend `UnicastRemoteObject` (and are therefore automatically exported). Consider instances `a` and `b`, respectively.

Now I call `m(a, b, 0)`. It compiles, but fails at runtime with the very non-informative

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
at $Proxy0.m(Unknown Source)
[... application specific sites]
```

Sadly, `NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0` is natively implemented and can not be inspected. So, I am at a total loss. Obviously, types match, otherwise the original code should not compile, right?

What can be reasons for this?

**Edit:** We use Java 6. The error can be reproduced on Ubuntu 11.04 32bit, Ubuntu 10.10 64bit and Windows 7 32bit.

**Edit 2:** I implemented some dummy methods on S to test individual parameters. Turns out, `s.n()`, `s.t0(b)` and `s.t1(0)` work as expected; only `s.t2(a)` fails. This implies that something is wrong with how I implemented `A`, doesn't it?

The only striking difference between `A` and `B` (aside from actual content, of course) is that `A` is a class extending `UnicastRemoteObject` and follows the convention of a remote interface but does not implement a distinguished remote interface. `B` is a remote interface an implementation of which I pass.

Comment: I would guess you changed your interface or implementation class without re-running rmic.

Comment: We use Java 6 so there should be any need for rmic. It has been legacy since 1.5.

Comment: What implementations of A and B you use on the server-side?

Comment: The one for `A` is the same on both server and client. The one for `B` is only available client-side, the server only knows interface `B`.

Comment: Is there any chance that client and server has different class files for interface 'S'?

Comment: No. Both jars drop out of the same maven build.

Comment: @Raphael You don't need stubs if you observe what it says about exporting and stubs in the class description for `UnicastRemoteObject`, i.e. always provide a port parameter when constructing or exporting. That doesn't entitle them to be described as 'legacy'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the information provided in my second edit is crucial.

You can only export/use as remote objects instances of classes that explicitly implement an interface which extends `Remote`. It is, in particular, *not* sufficient to have a class extending `UnicastRemoteObject`---even though that one implements `Remote`! In that case, everything compiles and exports just fine, but actually passing the object remotely causes the above exception.

I suppose that creating skeletons/stubs for a remote type for which no remote interface exists somehow fails. There should be a better treatment for that, but well.

**Edit:** To clarify: `UnicastRemoteObject` implements `Remote`. Now, having something like

```
class A extends UnicastRemoteObject { void m() throws RemoteException {} }
```

is *not* sufficient, even though `A` implements `Remote` indirectly. You will be able to instantiate (i.e. export), but not pass it remotely as an `A`.

You need to do

```
interface B extends Remote { void n() throws RemoteException; }
class BImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements B { void n() throws RemoteException { ... } }
```

Instances of `BImpl` can be passed remotely as `B` as you would expect. So it appears that you need to implement a distinguished remote interface aside from `Remote` if you want to have proper remote objects.

Comment: So A and B don't extend Remote?

Comment: Of course, but that alone is not sufficient. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: That alone *is* sufficient actually. Both A and B must extend Remote. Otherwise your title isn't satisfied, you don't *have* remote parameters.

Comment: Sorry; my "of course" was to mean "yes, they do extend `Remote`". Does the edit clarify things?